# Set up phabricator with LDAP authentication on Debian Jessie

Tags: web, ldap, debian, phabricator

On a server running Debian 8, how can I set up phabricator so that users are authenticated using a local LDAP server?

(Choosing LDAP because the same accounts should also be used by other web applications on the same server later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of ***** with secure passwords and store them safely.

Replace all occurrences of example.com with something sensible.

Use ssh X11 tunneling for the jxplorer application if you have no local X.

---

```
apt-get install emacs aptitude dbconfig-common debconf fonts-font-awesome jq \
    php5-fpm libjs-raphael php5-cli php5-curl mysql-server php5-mysql \
    php5-ldap po-debconf ucf nginx php5-apcu php5-gd npm python mc git \
    default-jdk jxplorer slapd xauth
```

New password for the mysql root user: *****

Admin password for LDAP: *****

---

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> grant all privileges on `phabricator\_%`.* to 'phabricator'@localhost identified by '*****';
mysql> exit
```

---

```
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

Enter

- domain: users.example.com,
- company name: example
- everywhere else, accept the defaults

---

start jxplorer, connect, enter

- Base DN: dc=users,dc=example,dc=com
- Level: user + password
- User DN: cn=admin,dc=users,dc=example,dc=com
- Password: What you used earlier

save connection settings if you like

Add new users below "users" with objectClass account,simpleSecurityObject:

- uid=developer,userPassword=*****,submit
- uid=reviewer,userPassword=*****,submit
- uid=webadmin,userPassword=*****,submit
- uid=anonymous,userPassword=*****,submit

Exit jxplorer

---

Download debian binary packages from testing distribution:
phabricator, arcanist, libphutil. Use
https://packages.debian.org/testing/phabricator to find the download links

```
# in the directory where these 3 packages have been downloaded to
dpkg -i *.deb
```

phabricator domain: phabricator.example.com
web server: nginx
MySQL administrator account username: phabricator

---

Setup DNS: Either have phabricator.example.com point to your server in DNS. 
Or add the ip address of the server to the client's /etc/hosts file 
as
      phabricator.example.com

---

```
service nginx restart
```

if this fails, then issue

```
nginx -t
```

to get the error message.

if the error message is

nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
then edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to include something like

```
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    ...
}
```

Open http://phabricator.example.com/ in a web browser. It displays:

Authentication Failure. Your login session is invalid. Try reloading the page and logging in again. If that does not work, clear your browser cookies.

So I reload.

---

On the web page:

- Phabricator Username: webadmin
- Real Name: webadmin
- Password: *****
- Email: webadmin@example.com

Open the Auth application,

- Add Authentication Provider Username/Password
- Add Authentication Provider LDAP
- Check Trust Email Addresses
- LDAP Host Name: localhost
- Base Distinguished Name: dc=users,dc=example,dc=com
- Search Attributes: uid
- Anonymous Username: uid=anonymous,dc=users,dc=example,dc=com
- Anonymous Password: what I used earlier
- Add Provider

---

Go to phabricator startpage, Open the people application, choose webadmin
Edit settings, Authentication External Accounts, Add External Account LDAP

- LDAP Username: webadmin
- LDAP Password: what I used earlier
- Link Accounts
- Confirm Account Link

Check if login via LDAP works:

- Log out
- Log in as webadmin over LDAP
- works

The user/password Auth Provider can now be disabled.
Log out and log in again to check

---

Check if user registration over LDAP works:

- Log out,
- LDAP Username: developer
- LDAP Password: What I set earlier
- Login/Register
- Phabricator Username: developer
- Real Name: developer
- Email: developer@example.com
- Register Phabricator account.

Account needs Approval

---

Log out and log in again as webadmin

- Open the People Application
- Approval Queue
- Thumb up

Go to Phabricator start page

- Open the Config Application
- Authentication
- auth.require-approval
- Set value to false
- save

Log out

---

Check login as developer

- works
- Log out

Check registration as reviewer

- works without approval